# Issue with Loading Pre-trained DQN Model Resulting in Lower Performance

Tags: python, tensorflow

Context:
I've been working with a Deep Q-Network (DQN) model for a reinforcement learning project. After training the model, I saved it and later loaded it for further evaluation. However, I noticed that the performance of the loaded model is significantly worse compared to the original pre-trained model's performance.

Problem:
The main issue seems to arise when I load the trained model; the performance drops dramatically, and the model behaves as if it hasn't learned anything from the training process. This is puzzling because the model performs well before saving.

```
class DQLAgent():
    def __init__(self, env, model_path=None):
        self.env = env
        self.state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.action_size = env.action_space.n
        self.gamma = 0.95
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.epsilon = 1
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.995
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
        
        if model_path:
            self.model = load_model(model_path)  # Load model if path provided
        else:
            self.model = self.build_model()  # Build new model otherwise

    def build_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(48, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='tanh'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return self.env.action_space.sample()
        else:
            act_values = self.model.predict(state,verbose = 0)
            return np.argmax(act_values[0])

    def replay(self, batch_size):
        if len(self.memory) < batch_size:
            return
        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
            target = reward if done else reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state,verbose = 0)[0])
            train_target = self.model.predict(state,verbose = 0)
            train_target[0][action] = target
            self.model.fit(state, train_target, verbose=0)

    def adaptiveEGreedy(self):
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay

# Initialize gym environment and the agent
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
agent = DQLAgent(env)

episodes = 50
batch_size = 32
round_results = []

for e in range(episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, 4])
    total_reward = 0

    while True:
        action = agent.act(state)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, 4])
        agent.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
        state = next_state
        agent.replay(batch_size)
        agent.adaptiveEGreedy()
        total_reward += reward

        if done:
            print(f'Episode: {e+1}, Total reward: {total_reward}')
            round_results.append(total_reward)
            break

agent.model.save('dql_cartpole_model.keras')
```

Demonstrate the effectiveness

```
model_path = 'dql_cartpole_model.keras'  # Update this path

env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
agent = DQLAgent(env, model_path=model_path)  

episodes = 100
round_results = []

for e in range(episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, 4])
    total_reward = 0

    while True:
        action = agent.act(state)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, 4])
        state = next_state
        total_reward += reward

        if done:
            print(f'Episode: {e+1}, Total reward: {total_reward}')
            round_results.append(total_reward)
            break

# Plot the rewards
plt.plot(round_results)
plt.title('Rewards per Episode')
plt.xlabel('Episode')
plt.ylabel('Total Reward')
plt.show()
```

edit add save_agent_state and load_agent_state to DQLAgent class to hopefully save epsilon and memory however still getting the same results

```
def save_agent_state(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump({
                'epsilon': self.epsilon,
                'memory': list(self.memory)  # Convert deque to list before saving
            }, file)

def load_agent_state(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            agent_state = pickle.load(file)
            self.epsilon = agent_state['epsilon']
            self.memory = deque(agent_state['memory'], maxlen=2000)
```

and added this in the end of training

```
agent.model.save('dql_cartpole_model.keras')
agent.save_agent_state('agent_state.pkl')
```

added this Demonstrate the effectiveness

```
model_path = 'dql_cartpole_model.keras'  # Update this path
agent.load_agent_state('agent_state.pkl')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you load your model with `agent = DQLAgent(env, model_path=model_path)`, `self.epsilon` is set (back) to `1`, meaning that the model always chooses random actions, and almost always in the first epochs with the decay. You should save the epsilon with the model, or set an evaluation flag for a trained model, where you always let the model choose the action and discard the chance for random exploration.
In your current implementation, your model also looses its `memory`, so if you save and load your model and want to train it further, it basically starts at 0 again with `epsilon` and `memory`.

Comment: add agent.save_agent_state('agent_state.pkl') to save epsilon and memory still the same issue

Comment: Please show the code of your solution.

Comment: have edited the question with the code of my solution let me know where I have made a mistake